# How to escape a BIOS failure?

Tags: uefi, bios, deepin

While attempting to install deepin linux onto my new netbook, I worked myself into a corner that I do not know how to escape. 
1) I loaded the deepin installer onto my USB stick as per instructions, no problems here.
2) I convinced my PC to boot to the USB (W8 was a pain about it, obviously).
3) I installed deepin to my eMMC, thus overwriting W8. Here the trouble began. When I rebooted (w/o the USB), Windows recovery kicked in and tried to fix W8, clearly failing as I had made no backups.
4) So I overwrote that partition as well, thinking it would boot to one, and I'd then delete the other.
5) When I rebooted, again w/o USB, I got the following message:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 083)
//copy right and patent bits

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.59 (01/13/14)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

In fiddling with the BIOS I turned on Legacy Mode to stop UEFI from trying to restore W8.
6) Inserting the USB and sending a key-strike only repeated the above message.
7) So I rebooted with the USB plugged in and attempted to enter BIOS through that, but did not manage. I tried F11, F10, F11, F12, and Escape. It only delayed the launch of the deepin install programme.
8) I know not how to reset CMOS on netbooks. I tried removing the battery and holding the power button for a while, but that didn't do the trick.
**EDIT**
The Netbook is an Acer ES1-111, which does not have a CMOS cell.

Comment: For instructions how to go in your netbook's BIOS setup, you need to provide the model number.  Note that the main battery is not what keeps the BIOS settings, as there is always a tiny battery inside the computer to handle that (but I don't recommend you try to open it).

Comment: Since you mentioned that you did change some options in the BIOS setup, you may already know how to go back inside to reset it, or to change the boot order so you can boot from USB.